# Js: Adding nested object literal items -- can't figure it out

Tags: jquery, object, nested, extend, literals

Here is my code:

```
Cart = {
    items: {
        id1: { cost: 55 },
        id3: { cost: 20 },
        id2: { cost: 15 }
    },

    blah blah blah
}
```

Now I want to add values to Cart.items with dynamic key & value and I'm stuck.

```
var id = 5;
Cart.items["id"+id].cost = 20;
```

I'm also using the jquery library so I'm not sure if .extend is better suited for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Also, standard Javascript convention is that only constructor functions should start with a capital letter: ideally, you should rename your `Cart` variable to `cart`

Comment: Thanks for that Forivall!

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted - click the little check mark on the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cart.items["id"+id]` may not exist.  Add this check first:

```
if (!Cart.items.hasOwnProperty("id" + id) {
   Cart.items["id" + id] = {};
}
```

Then, you can add keys/values at will at that level.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```js
Cart.items["id"+id] = {cost: 20};
```

This is because you have to declare a new object first. `Cart.items["id"+id]` is still undefined at this point.